# Images in WPF application disappear after navigating away

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm experiencing an interesting phenomenon in my WPF application.

I have two separate views affected - one that allows editing of statistics and one that allows editing of templates.  On both of these views I have a navigation bar that on  allows the user to navigate forward and backward through search results and I use buttons with an image for the Back/Next UI.  If I go navigate through statistics, and then through templates, the images show up fine; however, if I go back to statistics, the images no longer appear, but the buttons and navigation works.  If I go back to templates, the images are still there.  If I do templates first, then statistics and back to templates, the same order of behavior persists - statistics keeps the images.  So it seems to do with the order, and not the views.

I have the images added to my project and have `Build Action` set to `Resource`.  I have them referenced in my `ResourceDictionary` like so:

```
 <Image x:Key="ico_Right" Source="/GOKOMS.Home;component/Images/nav_single_right.png" />
```

Within my View itself, I reference as

```
<Button Content="{StaticResource ico_Right}" Width="35" Height="35"
        Visibility="{Binding Vis_Next, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ToolTip="Next Record"
        Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
        CommandParameter="Next"
        />
```

I know it's not the binding as the button itself appears; I've even removed that just to be certain.  It feels like this is the pertinent code, but I can add more if needed.  Has anyone experienced something like this before?

Comment: Are the buttons visible but they have no content?

Comment: Correct - visible but no content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your Image control resource can only be attached to one place in the visual tree and you are trying to attach it to 2 different button elements (on different views)

You could try restructuring your views so that there is only one instance of the navigation menu, or you could create multiple image resources, or you could use a BitmapImage resource instead:

Resource:

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="ico_Right" UriSource="/GOKOMS.Home;component/Images/nav_single_right.png" />
```

Button:

```
<Button Width="35" Height="35"
        Visibility="{Binding Vis_Next, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        ToolTip="Next Record"
        Command="{Binding NavCommand}"
        CommandParameter="Next">
    <Image Source="{StaticResource ico_Right}" />
</Button>
```

Comment: Perfect - I was not aware of that fact about the image control.  I have gone with your BitmapImage suggesting and it works.  Just two minor things - the Content attribute should be removed from the Button control, and the Image control doesn't need to x:Key attribute.  But other than that it's working perfectly.

Comment: @bassrek Thanks, I was just writing code in my head

Comment: No problem - I assumed that was the case and just wanted to point out incase someone else has the same issue in the future.